# Azure Search - Accent insensitive analyzer not working when sorting

Tags: c#, azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search. I have a model with a property with this attributes

```
[IsRetrievable(true), IsSearchable, IsSortable, Analyzer("standardasciifolding.lucene")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

I want the search to be accent insensitive. Although it is working when searching/filtering, it is not working when sorting the results. So, If I have words that start with an accent and I sort alphabetically, those results appear at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I verified your use case by creating an index with Id and a Title field that uses the standardasciifolding.lucene analyzer. I then submitted the 4 sample records via the REST API:

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "1",
        "Title" : "øks"
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "2",
        "Title": "aks"
    },      
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "3",
        "Title": "áks"
    },
    {
        "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
        "Id": "4",
        "Title": "oks"
    }                   
]}
```

I then ran a query with $orderby specified. I used Postman with variables wrapped in double curly braces. Replace with relevant values for your environment.

https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{INDEX_NAME}}/docs?search=*&$count=true&$select=Id,Title&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}&$orderby=Title asc

The results were returned as

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://<my-search-service>.search.windows.net/indexes('dg-test-65224345')/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "@odata.count": 4,
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1.0,
            "Id": "2",
            "Title": "aks"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.0,
            "Id": "4",
            "Title": "oks"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.0,
            "Id": "3",
            "Title": "áks"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1.0,
            "Id": "1",
            "Title": "øks"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the sort order is indeed a, o, á, ø which confirms what you find. The order is inversed if I change to $orderby=Title desc. Thus, the sorting appears to be done by the original value and not the normalized value. We can check how the analyzer works, by posting a sample title to the analyzer with a POST request to

https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{INDEX_NAME}}/docs?search=*&$count=true&$select=Id,Title&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}&$orderby=Title asc

```
{  "text": "øks",  "analyzer": "standardasciifolding.lucene" }
```

Which produces the following tokens

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://<my-search-service>.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2020_06_30_Preview.AnalyzeResult",
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "oks",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 3,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "øks",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 3,
        "position": 0
    }
]
```

}

You could try to define a custom analyzer which produces a normalized version, but I am not sure it will work. For example, the sorting does not appear to support case-insensitive sorting which would be related to this use case where multiple characters should be sorted as if they were a normalized version. E.g. a and A cannot be sorted as the same character according to [this user voice entry](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328658-case-insensitive-sorting-for-string-fields) (feel free to vote for it).

**WORKAROUND**

The best workaround I can think of is to process the data yourself. Let **Title** contain the original title, and then create another field called *TitleNormalized* where you store the normalized version. In your application you would then query with $orderby on the **TitleNormalized** field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature that allows you to enable normalization while filtering. Please check out the [Text normalization for case-insensitive filtering, faceting and sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers) feature that's in Preview.

You can update your index to use this "normalizer" feature for the fields in which you'd like case-insensitive order-by operations.

You don't need a separate field `TitleNormalized` anymore. You can add `"normalizer": "standard"` to the `Title` field, and  $orderBy=Title will sort in the order you'd like, ignoring casing and accents.

The "standard" normalizer is pre-defined. If you'd like other filters to be applied, please look at [predefined and custom normalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#predefined-normalizers)

```json
"index": {
    "name": "your-name-here",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Title", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true, "normalizer":"standard"}
    ]
}
```