# Azure Search Normalized Lowercase Field

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am unable to add a normalized copy of the "Title" field to our search index. Ultimately, I'm trying to use this field for case-insensitive order by. Currently, titles are returned in the following order (with $orderBy=TitleCaseInsensitive):

1. Abc
2. Bbc
3. abc

And instead I want: Abc->abc->Bbc. I have forked the "Title" field out into two fields via a Field Mapping and am then applying a Custom Analyzer with the "lowercase" tokenFilter, to the normalized field. Can someone explain why I am not getting the desired results? Here is the relevant portion of the index definition:

```json
"index":{
    "name": "current-local-inventory",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "TitleCaseInsensitive","indexAnalyzer":"caseInsensitiveAnalyzer","searchAnalyzer":"keyword", "type": "Edm.String","filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true},
        {"name": "Title", "type": "Edm.String","filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true},
    ],
    "analyzers": [
        {
            "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
            "name":"caseInsensitiveAnalyzer",
            "charFilters":[],
            "tokenizer":"keyword_v2",
            "tokenFilters":["lowercase"]
        }
      ]
},
"indexers":[{
    "fieldMappings" : [
        {"sourceFieldName" : "Title", "targetFieldName" : "Title" },
        {"sourceFieldName" : "Title", "targetFieldName" : "TitleCaseInsensitive" }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in the related post [Azure Search - Accent insensitive analyzer not working when sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224345/azure-search-accent-insensitive-analyzer-not-working-when-sorting). When you include the lowercase token filter it only affects search and not sorting. See [Azure Search User Voice entry Case-insensitive sorting for string fields](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a60dd20a-0425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8)

My suggested workaround as I explain in the related post is to create a forked/shadow property. However, using an analyzer with a lowercase token filter won't help. The only way I could get your example working was to include a copy of your Title property that was already lowercased. Notice that I don't use fieldMapping and I don't use different analyzers for indexing and search like you have in your example.

**CREATE INDEX**

Create the index. Replace variables wrapped in angle brackets as suitable for your env.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8761DCBBCCD00\"",
"name": "{{INDEX_NAME}}",
"defaultScoringProfile": null,
"fields": [

    {"name": "Id", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": false, "filterable": true, "retrievable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "key": true, "indexAnalyzer": null, "searchAnalyzer": null, "analyzer": null, "synonymMaps": [] }, 
    {"name": "TitleCaseInsensitive","indexAnalyzer": null, "searchAnalyzer": null, "analyzer": "caseInsensitiveAnalyzer", "type": "Edm.String","filterable": false, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true},
    {"name": "Title", "type": "Edm.String","filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true}
],  
"scoringProfiles": [],
"corsOptions": null,
"suggesters": [],
"analyzers": [        {
        "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name":"caseInsensitiveAnalyzer",
        "charFilters":[],
        "tokenizer":"keyword_v2",
        "tokenFilters":["lowercase"]
    }],
"tokenizers": [],
"tokenFilters": [],
"charFilters": [],
"encryptionKey": null
```

}

**UPLOAD**

Upload three sample documents.

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "Id": "1",
            "Title": "Abc",
            "TitleCaseInsensitive": "abc"
        },
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "Id": "2",
            "Title": "abc",
            "TitleCaseInsensitive": "abc"
        },
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "Id": "3",
            "Title": "Bbc",
            "TitleCaseInsensitive": "bbc"
        }
    ]
}
```

**QUERY**

Then, query with $orderby on your lowercased (normalized) property.

[https://{{SEARCH_SVC}}.{{DNS_SUFFIX}}/indexes/{{INDEX_NAME}}/docs?search=*&$count=true&$select=Id,Title,TitleCaseInsensitive&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version={{API-VERSION}}&$orderby=TitleCaseInsensitive asc](https://%7B%7BSEARCH_SVC%7D%7D.%7B%7BDNS_SUFFIX%7D%7D/indexes/%7B%7BINDEX_NAME%7D%7D/docs?search=*&$count=true&$select=Id,Title,TitleCaseInsensitive&searchMode=all&queryType=full&api-version=%7B%7BAPI-VERSION%7D%7D&$orderby=TitleCaseInsensitive%20asc)

And you'll get the expected results where Title is sorted in a case-insensitive way.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://<your-search-service>.search.windows.net/indexes('dg-test-65526118')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"@odata.count": 3,
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1.0,
        "Id": "2",
        "TitleCaseInsensitive": "abc",
        "Title": "abc"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 1.0,
        "Id": "1",
        "TitleCaseInsensitive": "abc",
        "Title": "Abc"
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 1.0,
        "Id": "3",
        "TitleCaseInsensitive": "bbc",
        "Title": "Bbc"
    }
]
```

}

I would love to be corrected with a simple way to accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to add a lowercase field to my data source. Even if I could, it would  become untenable as we tried to support additional sortable fields. I need to find a way to do it by forking the data source field to two fields in the index document

Comment: Ok. When you say data source do you mean that you use an Azure Search Indexer with a data source defined in the portal? How you get the data into the index matters. If you use an Azure Search indexer you can define a custom processing pipeline. If you submit via the SDK you cannot use the built-in enrichment pipeline, but you can obviously do any processing you want.

Comment: The processing is called Skillset. Sorry, could not remember the actual name of it.

Comment: I do use an indexer, yes. There is SQL view that the data is coming from and an indexer that's running against it

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [Text normalization for case-insensitive filtering, faceting and sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers) feature that's in Preview.

You can update your index to use this "normalizer" feature for the fields in which you'd like case-insensitive order-by operations.

You don't need a separate field `TitleCaseInsensitive` anymore. You can add `"normalizer": "lowercase"` to the `Title` field, and  $orderBy=Title will sort in the order you'd like, ignoring casing.

The "lowercase" normalizer is pre-defined. If you'd like other filters to be applied, please look at [predefined and custom normalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#predefined-normalizers)

```json
"index": {
    "name": "current-local-inventory",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Title", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true, "normalizer":"lowercase"}
    ]
},
"indexers":[{
    "fieldMappings" : [
        {"sourceFieldName" : "Title", "targetFieldName" : "Title" }
    ]
}]
```